# Switching user in node spawn child processes

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

How can one change a child processes' uid/gid based on a user-supplied username and password without granting node root or other special privileges?

Basically the child process equivalent of:

```
su diffuser
//enter password
```

Things I've tried:

- **passing uid and gid to spawn as options**:  works, but requires special permissions be first granted to node (e.g. running as root).  For security, it would be better to keep node process privileges to a minimum.
- **spawn('su', ['diffuser'])**: this returns *su: must be run from a terminal.*
- **spawn('sudo', ['-S', 'su', 'diffuser', '-c', 'whoami'])**:  works but requires a sudoer password vs user password.

Anyone got any other ideas?

this is for the linux version of node.

Comment: The fact that your second approach has a error status specifically forbidding this, the implication is that _you should not be attempting to programmatically invoke `su`._

Comment: @Patrick Roberts, without understanding my use case how have you reached this conclusion? Node already allows one to do so, except it requires special permissions, which I would prefer to avoid - and which would be less secure than su.